# Поиск с выводом части текста

Tags: python, django

вопрос у меня отчасти телепатический, но меня устроит если только укажете направление, в котором копать

сделал встроенными средствами django1.6 простейший поиск. вот его основа

def search_result(request):
    message = ''
    result = None

```
if 'search_phrase' in request.GET and request.GET['search_phrase']:
    try:
        search_phrase = request.GET['search_phrase']
        result = Page.objects.filter(Q(title__icontains=search_phrase)|Q(content__icontains=search_phrase))
        if not len(result):
            message = u'По вашему запросу не найдено ни одной статьи.'
    except Exception:
        message = u'Извините. В данный момент доступ к базе данных невозможен. Попробуйте повторить ваш запрос позже.'
else:
    message = u'Вы не ввели данные в строку запроса'

t = loader.get_template('search_result.html')
c = RequestContext(request, {
    'result': result, 
    'message': message,
    'title': 'Результаты поиска',
})
return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```

он работает, но в результате выводит только список заголовков страниц, в которых нашлисб совпадения, а хотелось бы чтобы выводилось так же часть текста, в котором нашлась искомая фраза. например 100 символов до, сама фраза поиска, сто символов после. такое возможно сделать, используя только встроенные средства? если да, то как скажите пожалуйста

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Content` у вас есть, в Питоне с работой с текстом все неплохо (если не считать возни с юникодом, для вас это неактуально).

```
for p in pages:
    position = p.lower().find(search_phrase.lower())
    p.content_snippet = p[position - 100:position + len(searchPhrase) + 100]
```

Или что-то вроде